# How to configure subscription product purchase using paypal in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, paypal, recurring

I need to configure subscription product in **Magento 2** while placing an order with **Paypal payment** option

In **Magento 1** I have done this rewriting method the `getStandardCheckoutFormFields` file **Mage_Paypal_Model_Standard**

where I can merge the additional params of ***recurring profile*** by follwoing way

```
public function getStandardCheckoutFormFields()
{
    $result = parent::getStandardCheckoutFormFields();

    $result["redirect_cmd"] = "_xclick-subscriptions";

    $result = array_merge($result, array(

      "a3" => round(500,2),
      "p3" =>"6" ,
      "t3" => "M",
      "src" => "1",
      "sra" => "1",
      "item_name" => "Subscription Product",
      "item_number" => "12345",

    ));

    return $result;

}
```

How can I do this in Magento 2

I have found instead of form submitting these all things are done by API call from `vendor\magento\module-paypal\Model\Api\Nvp.php`.

But I don't know how this get here 
from

> `vendor\magento\module-paypal\Controller\Express\Start.php`

to

> `vendor\magento\module-paypal\Model\Api\Nvp.php`

file this will be great help if anyone can parse the path.

Thank you